# Galaxy S4 "sound and shot" feature - extract sound

Tags: photos, samsung-galaxy-s-4, audio-recording

The Galaxy S4 has a neat feature called "sound and shot" (maybe "sound & shot"?). It will let you record up to 9 seconds of sound with a picture.

However, I want *just the sound* out of a picture I took, and I cannot find how to do that. There is no intuitive way to do this in the current version of Android or the gallery app. I know they must be storing the sound file somewhere, but apparently it is not next to the picture.

[This article](http://allaboutgalaxys4.com/galaxy-s4-features-explained/sound-and-shot/) explains that it is not possible to listen to the sound on anything but an S4. Seems kinda short-sighted to me.

My guesses are they implemented by either:

1. storing the sound hidden within the .jpeg itself or
2. they have a separate hidden place they put a .wav or .3gp file or something.

I have searched the phone for the latter, and cannot find it. Given that the file size is almost double a normal photo sitting right net to it, I am inclined to think it is buried in the .jpeg file.

Any guesses as to how to get that out? and what the file format is?

Comment: Why don't you use normal audio recording app if you only want sound?

Comment: That's the obvious solution... but I recorded this on the other side of the world and now realized there is no way to get it out!

Comment: Then play the photo on your phone and record with another phone or computer.

Comment: Good work-around option. I got what I needed, but this question is more about my fascination on how they "hid" the audio file. I have a few theories, including what I mentioned in the post. The other idea was Alternate Data Streams, or something like it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(file_system)

Answer (score 6):

When using "Sound & shot" mode with the Samsung Galaxy S4 camera, the audio is stored as a WAV file that is embedded into a metadata tag within the JPEG. Here is how to extract the audio using ExifTool on a computer (not android). ExifTool can run on Unix platforms, Macintosh OS X, and Windows. If you are running linux, it might be available through your package repositories.

1) Install [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html) on your computer.

2) Transfer the file of interest to your computer for extraction. (I'll leave that part up to you)

3) Now extract it. In my example, we assume the filename is called '20160520_061539.jpg', and the operating system is linux. You might have to  make adjustments to the process for other operating systems. In my case, the name of the tag which stores the audio is 'EmbeddedAudioFile'. To extract it, open a terminal and do:

> exiftool -b -EmbeddedAudioFile 20160520_061539.jpg > 20160520_061539.wav

You should now have a WAV audio file called 20160520_061539.wav in the present directory.

Comment: Brilliant answer - this removes the need to have a Android S4 to decode old files with missing audio!

Answer (score 3):

It is inside the JPG and you may extract it with an app, such as [SGS4 Audio Extractor by Accalio](http://www.accalio.com/SGS4-Audio-Extractor.307.0.html).

> #### A complementary utility for Samsung Galaxy S4 users
>
> Samsung has introduced the Sound&shot feature which we use at Accalio when taking whiteboard notes.
>
> As we haven't found a software to extract sound files from the JPG files taken by Samsung phone, we've decided to create a small utility for this task.
>
> Feel free to use and redistribute the app. Please note, that there is no warranty provided and the app may not extract files correctly or rewrite outputs.
>
> **Download [SGS4audiojpg.zip](http://accalio.com/fileadmin/downloads/SGS4audiojpg.zip) (563 232kB)**
>
> The WAV files can be played back with VLC player only. Windows Media player is unable to play it at this moment and we will consider a new version if requested...
>
> ( More about the feature : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDAPEFmbjZU )

Hope it helps.

Comment: Cool! how do I know this isn't loaded with a virus?

Comment: Just use antivirus if you are afraid. Don't worry, I can assure you that the file is clean. It is hosted on a official web of Accalio. You can check the company and its references...

Comment: The file is 100% clean. Nice job on the development side!

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to obtain the audio that works perfectly on my Samsung Galaxy S4.

### Brief Version

Tell the phone to convert the `Sound and Shot` files into  `.mp4` video files, then copy them off using a USB cable.

### (optional) Detailed Version

- On your phone, go into `Gallery` and long press on an album to select it. A green tick mark will appear on the top right of the album.
- Click on the `Share` icon (top right).
- It will ask you if you want to share the `Sound and Shot` files as (a) `jpegs` or (b) `video`

  - (if you have no `Sound and Shot` files, this question will not appear).
  - Select (b) `video`.
- It will now say `Processing`, and it will go through the `DCIM` directory on your phone and convert the `Sound and Shot` `.jpg` files into `.mp4` files. Essentially, what its doing at this point is extracting the sound from the `jpg`, and creating an `.mp4` video file out of it with one frame, and up to 9 seconds of audio.
- When it gets to the page `Share via`, do not go any further, but:

  - Connect your phone via USB.
  - Browse to `Computer\<Phone>\Phone\DCIM`
  - Copy all of the new `.mp4` files from your phone to your PC.

The converted files will have the same name as the `.jpg` files, but will have extension `.mp4`.

You can play the video files using VLC Media Player.

You can now use any 3rd party program to extract the audio from the `.mp4` files, if you really want to (but I don't see why you would).

### Update

***You can use this method to extra audio from old `Sound and Shot` files on your PC that you thought you had lost the audio for!*** As the sound is always embedded in the `.jpg` files, you can:

- Connect your Android to the PC using USB;
- Copy the old `.jpg` files to the `DCIM` folder on your phone;
- Repeat the steps above.
- Copy the new `.mp4` files back to your PC.

Note that if the files do not appear in the gallery after you have copied them from PC to phone, kill the gallery app, plug/remove/plug the USB cable to force a refresh, or just restart the phone.

### Update

I am running the latest version of Android OS as of May 2015.